# Where to place non clustered index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, index-tuning, query-performance

Execution plan clearly showing that one of my table used in query is useing Clustered Index Scan. From this node, how can i guess that which columns should be part of my non clustered index key and which columns should i use in incluse list. 
I am using SQL Server 2008/R2

Comment: Please post your DDL, as well as your query.

Comment: When index tuning, please don't guess. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In there interest of showing a generalized example until we see your particular DDL and query, take the below as a basic example:

```
create table SomeTable
(
    id int identity(1, 1) not null
        primary key clustered,
    AnotherInt int null,
    SomeData nvarchar(1024) null
)
go

insert into SomeTable(AnotherInt, SomeData)
values(null, null)
go 1000

update SomeTable
set 
    AnotherInt = id * 3 + 152,
    SomeData = 'My ID value is ' + cast(id as nvarchar(16))
```

So we have a test table, **SomeTable**, with a clustered index.  Execute the below query:

```
select SomeData
from SomeTable
where AnotherInt < 200
```

This causes a Clustered Index Scan, like you are seeing:

[image]

So analyzing the query, we have the column **AnotherInt** that is in the `WHERE` clause and being searched on.  We are also retrieving the **SomeData** column, so to prevent a key lookup in the clustered index (or the optimizer may even just use a Clustered Index Scan again), we'll have **SomeData** as an `INCLUDE` column:

```
create nonclustered index IX_SomeData_AnotherInt_SomeData
on SomeTable(AnotherInt) 
include (SomeData)
go
```

Now, executing the same query above:

```
select SomeData
from SomeTable
where AnotherInt < 200
```

SQL Server will utilize that non-clustered index to return the data.  It is a covering index, because it won't need to do a lookup on the clustered index for the remaining data:

[image]

Through creating a prudent NCI, we have now eliminated the CI Scan in lieu of an Index Seek.

Comment: @aasim.abdullah No problem at all.  If you post your `CREATE TABLE` batch and any other surrounding DDL (i.e. `CREATE INDEX ...`) as well as your query, I can use your particular situation and go from there.  Otherwise, if this answers your question, please consider upvoting and marking this answer as accepted.